# Property of Jacobson Radical

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to show that: 
**For a ring R, if R has no left primitive ideals, then J(R) = R , where J(R) is the Jacobson radical of R.**

I have tried in the following way:

*Let R have no primitive ideals and J(R) $\ne$ R.
 Then, there exists a simple left R-module A whose annihilator is properly contained in R. Then this annihilator is a left primitive ideal of R which contradicts our assumption.*

Is the above proof correct or am I missing out on something?

P.S. This is a part of 4 equivalence statements given in *page 428 of the book Algebra by T.W. Hungerford(Chapter 9, Section 2)*.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, for taking the time to properly cite everything you were looking at. It was immensely helpful for tracking down the issue you faced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Techncally it is correct, but you may as well just reason directly:

Suppose $R$ has no left primitive ideals. Then it has no left simple modules, because the existence of simple left modules implies their annihilators are left primitive (and proper) ideals. Therefore by the "convention" mentioned on the page, $J(R)=R$.